# PHP Validation and storing information into Session Variables

Tags: php, html, validation, session

I'm setting up 2 text-boxes and one drop down options list in html. I'm trying to use php to validate if these text box are filled in or not. If clicked on the submit button ('btnCalculate'), the validation occurs, if nothing in the text boxes, there will be an error message that pops up beside it ('pamountErrorMsg, irateErrorMsg'). If there is substance that is typed into the textboxes, the browser will save the information into Session["pamount"] or "irate". I am having trouble validating the blank text boxes and adding the variables into Session before I can use them in the next page. Right now it is not validating anything at all. What is wrong with my syntax, if any?

Was thinking of using just using 
     "php? $pamount = $_SESSION["pamount"]; ?>" to create the variable I need to read the session variable, is that correct?

**PHP**

```
session_start();    // start PHP session! 

header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');

$pamountErrorMsg = "";
$irateErrorMsg = "";

$btnCalculate = $_GET['btnCalculate'];
$irate = $_GET['irate'];
$pamount = $_GET['pamount'];    
    $y2d = $_GET['y2d'];
if(isset($btnCalculate))
{
    if(strlen(trim($pamount)) <= 0)
    {
        $pamountErrorMsg = "Principal Amount cannot be empty";
        $irateErrorMsg = "";
    }
    else if(strlen(trim($irate)) <= 0)
    {
        $irateErrorMsg = "The interest rate cannot be empty";
        $pamountErrorMsg = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["pamount"] = $_GET["pamount"];
        $_SESSION["irate"] = $_GET["irate"];
                    $_SESSION["y2d"] = $_GET["y2d"];
        header("Location: Lab3DisclamerZCL.php");
        exit( );
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method='get' action="Result.php">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Principal Amount
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type='text' class='input' name='pamount' size='30' />
        </td>
        <td class='error'>
        <?php echo $pamountErrorMsg; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Interest Rate (%)
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type='text' class='input' name='irate' size='30' />
        </td>
        <td class='error'>
        <?php echo $irateErrorMsg; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Years to Deposite
        </td>
        <td>
        <select name='y2d' selected='5'>
                <option value='1'>1</option>
                <option value='2'>2</option>
                <option value='3'>3</option>
                <option value='4'>4</option>
                <option value='5' selected='selected'>5</option>
                <option value='6'>6</option>
                <option value='7'>7</option>
                <option value='8'>8</option>
                <option value='9'>9</option>
                <option value='10'>10</option>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type='submit' class='button' name='btnCalculate' value='Calculate'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type='reset' class='button' name='btnReset' value='Reset' />

            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
    </form>
```

**My Result.php** (*in progress*)

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
<?php 
session_start();    // retrieve PHP session! 
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
if (!isset($_SESSION["name"]))
{
    header("Location: Calculator.php");
    exit( );
}
        if(!isset($_SESSION["pamount"]))
{
    $pamount = $_SESSION["pamount"];
}
if(!isset($_SESSION["irate"]))
{
    $irate = $_SESSION["irate"];
}
if(!isset($_SESSION["pamount"]))
{
    $y2d = $_SESSION["y2d"];
}
?> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Results</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h3 class="distinct">Thank you <?php echo $_SESSION["name"]?>, for using out deposite calculation tool.</h3>
<p>Following is the results of calculation </p>
<form action='Result.php' method='post'>
<table>
                 <?php


                 $pamount = $_SESSION["pamount"];
                 $irate = $_SESSION["irate"];
                 $y2d = $_SESSION["y2d"];
                $runningPrincipal = $pamount;

                for($i = 1; $i <= $y2d; ++$i)
                {
                    $interest = $runningPrincipal * $irate * 0.01;

                    printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>\$%.2f</td><td>\$%.2f</td></tr>", $i, $runningPrincipal, $interest);

                    $runningPrincipal += $interest;

                }
                ?>
                </table>
                </form>
<?php session_destroy();?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well your `y2d` html is wrong, you need `value` attributes for your drop down list, thats the first problem.

Comment: As a general note, it's usually bad practice to use tables for layout, yes, even in forms. The form controls themselves (`<fieldset>`, `<label>`) can easily be used to layout the form nicely.

Comment: Also by `Right now it is not validating anything at all.` what do you mean? What error do you get if any?

Comment: I press the btnCalculate, and it brings me to the next page without any validation even if I left the textboxes empty

Comment: Try using `if(strlen(trim($pamount)) <= 0)` instead and same for `$irate` too, also does the script redirect like it should or does it just not even go into into the main `if` statement?

Comment: It redirects into Result.php like it should. Am I saving my $pamount, $irate, and $y2d variable correctly into Session?

Comment: Well you not saving `y2d` there since it isn't coded in but I'm sure it is on your version. Cna you var_dump your variables and edit this question with their content? I think there might be something in them despite you leaving the text box blank, prolly some browser thing.

Comment: var_dump($pamount);? undefined index.

Comment: @GivenPie You cannot use `$_POST` for setting the session variables as you are using `get` as html form method ( `<form method='get' action="Result.php">` ). Use `$_GET` or better `$_REQUEST'.

Comment: Okay, made changes, although didn't make difference in result.

Comment: @GivenPie before `header("Location: Lab3DisclamerZCL.php");`, enter `print_r($_GET);exit;` and check the values submitted.

Comment: After adding print_r($_GET);exit;, the same problem occurs where no text boxes are filled in but the form still changes pages. It feels like the submit button is broken and the php script doesn't run the validation.

Comment: @GivenPie When you say the 'form changes page', do you mean the final page is `Result.php` or `Lab3DisclamerZCL.php` ?

Comment: You mean undefined index as in a E_NOTICE error? That's not possible. It is possible to get undefined index when trying to access the arrays if the indexes dont exist but not when var_dumping the variables.

Comment: @air4x the final page is the Result.php

Comment: @GivenPie is the HTML markup in the same file i.e. `Result.php` ? if not enter `echo $pamountErrorMsg; echo $irateErrorMsg;` at the absolute end of `Result.php` and check.

Comment: There is 3 .php docs, one is Lab3DisclamerZCL saving your name into a session variable, that works fine. Calculator.php is the code above in which it prompts for the $pamount (principal amount) and $irate (interest rate), and you choose the years to deposit option. I have just posted Result.php, you can see what I am doing with my session variables. I think i need to create a if(isset) statement to make sure my session variables $pamount, $irate, and $y2d are saved into the session to be used in Result.php

Comment: @GivenPie you need to do the validation on the same page, where the HTML form is given i.e. `Calculator.php`. On successful validation you will assign the entered values to session variables, and redirect to `Result.php` where you can do the calculation and display result.

Comment: Oh my gosh! Your right. I changed the header(Location: Result.php) and the action='Calculate' and it works now. I finally understand how validation works now. Thanks so much air4x. You can copy and paste your answer and I will publish it as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the validation on the same page, where the HTML form is given i.e. Calculator.php. On successful validation you will assign the entered values to session variables, and redirect to Result.php where you can do the calculation and display result.